# how to enable/activate a plugin per Cpanel

Tags: plugins, activation

The webdesign company deleted my access to plugins in my wordpress panel

so, I downloaded the plugin.zip and extracted it in **wp-content/plugins**

In **phpmyadmin/wp-options/active-plugin**
there was not the name of my plugins ...

my plugin name is : **persian-woocommerce-sms**

so someone, please, explain to me how should I **activate/enable** and **use** my plugin
**in baby steps**

I am thankful to your beautiful minds (praying hands))

Comment: I'd talk to your designers and ask them why they've removed your permission: I'm not sure you want to fight them over this, and you'll still need to work with them in the future. Can you edit the database from cpanel? You'll either need to do that or to temporarily edit WordPress core to run some code for you to make the edits (or maybe a temporary mu-plugin), and you probably want to grant yourself the role back rather to activate it through the admin panel so that any activation steps get run correctly.

Comment: But broadly you should solve the issue with your designers not trying to work around it with a technical solution.

Comment: @Rup thank you for your comment. they did this for website security and SEO stuff.
so there won't be a chance for us to mess up the website.

I dunno if it would be easy to reset the wp core to its original form
but maybe we will have to talk it with them.